# Can I change the wattage of a light in nodes?

Tags: node-editor, lighting

I recently found out that you can change the temperature of a bulb using a black body node, but it would be super helpful to be able to set the bulbs strength in nodes too. Is this a feature in Blender?

Comment: Like the emission node has a color field, it also have a strenght field that's using the default units (they depend on the light type). What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: By default you get an emission node and a light output node. So far as I know the emission strength is sperate from the bulb's power displayed in the properties panel. I guess what I'm looking for is a more node based workflow for lighting.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a node that can change the strength of the light. a way to copy strength values between lights faster would be preferable too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emission strength is a multiplier to the power in watts.

Example:
[image]

[image]

So, in theory we can change this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

and it appears to work perfectly.